# How to change external button text in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to edit the external button text of a WooCommerce product in functions.php. The following code generates the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $button_text ); ?></button>
```

I already tried multiple code from other people but every solution does not seem to work. The code I think is most close is the one below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_add_to_cart_text( $button_text ) {
  // Change the button text here
    $s = array(
        'Bekijk'  => 'Bekijk bij BOL.COM ➞'
    );
    return strtr($button_text, $s);
}
```

But somehow the button text stays the same, how can I fix this? :)

I already tried multiple codes from other people but nothing seems to work...

Comment: External button? Please share more details for better clarification.?

Comment: @mujuonly Instead of a 'normal' product we promote affiliate products on external websites. In WooCommerce you have the option to link to an external website with the button. We want to edit that default text with our affiliate partners name in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change add to cart text on product archives page
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text', 10, 2);
// Change add to cart text on single product page
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text', 10, 2);

function woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text($button_text, $product) {
    if ('external' == $product->get_type()) {
        $button_text = __('Add to Cart Button Text for affiliate', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

You can add the above code snippet into active theme functions.php to change the button text for external products in hop page and single product page

Comment: Thanks for the code, unfortunately that does not work. It's still the default. To make it more strange, if I change the button text for a specific product the text also stays default. The button_text variable must be set somewhere, I can't find where

Comment: @ThijsvanHal Check by switching the theme if it works